# MySQL duplicate names to be returned

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following syntax:

```
 | ID | institution_course1_id | institution_course2_id |
```

where application1_id and application2_id references to the same table. I need to get the values of both (so in other words I want to retrieve the name of each application)

I tried to join the tables but I am still only receiving 1 name in my results. Here is my SQL I use:

```
 SELECT * FROM `client_applications` 
LEFT JOIN `institution_courses` `name1` 
   ON `client_applications`.`institution_course1_id`=`name1`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `institution_courses` `name2` 
   ON `client_applications`.`institution_course2_id`=`name2`.`id` 
WHERE `client_applications`.`client_id`=?
```

Is there a way for me to return in my results all rows from client_applications and then have 2 seperate added keys as "name1" and "name2" based on the above?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Hi! Could you share the schema of both the tables you are trying to join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your problem is the application reading the results.  Try putting in different aliases ("column names") for the two names:

```
SELECT ca.*, name1.name as name1, name2.name as name2
FROM `client_applications` ca LEFT JOIN
     `institution_courses` `name1`
      ON ca.`institution_course1_id` = `name1`.`id` LEFT JOIN 
      `institution_courses` `name2`
      ON ca.`institution_course2_id` = `name2`.`id`
WHERE ca.`client_id` = ?;
```

Otherwise your query looks fine (although I added an alias for the first table as well).

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
SELECT ca.*, (select name1.name  from name1 where ca.`institution_course1_id` = `name1`.`id`) as name1,(select name1.name  from name1 where ca.`institution_course2_id` = `name1`.`id`) as name2
FROM `client_applications` ca 
WHERE ca.`client_id` = ?;
```